# Win32_Processor has no processor id

Tags: windows, cpu, wmi, bios, cpuid

Almost system has win32 processor id, but I find one system has no processor id.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor
Caption           : Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 5
DeviceID          : CPU0
Manufacturer      : GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed     : 3600
Name              : Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10850K CPU @ 3.60GHz
SocketDesignation :

PS C:\Windows\system32> (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).ProcessorId
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

It returns null. so I use MiTeC SMBIOS Explorer to check smbios, there is no processor information (type 4)

[image: sbe_picture]

It's not virtual machine. Is any reason it doesn't has processor information? If exist something bios option please tell me..

System Informaion

- cpu: i9-10850k
- baseboard: asus rog strix z490-h gaming
- os: windows 10 pro 21h2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMBIOS processor id in processor information (4) is documented as the values of registers EAX and EDX for CPUID leaf 1 on x86. If you actually care about the CPU features then call `IsProcessorFeaturePresent` or CPUID yourself.

I don't know why the value is not reported. Most likely because the BIOS is not setting the values for it or Microsoft removed the support in WMI.